# Groovy/Java open filePath with special characters

Tags: java, linux, grails, special-characters

I am trying to open a file on a Grails server but the problem is that my path contains special characters such as Ç

It worked fine on my OSX environment, but since I uploaded it to the linux production environment, the error "No such file or directory" pops out

The locale is set to fr_FR.UTF-8

**EDIT:**

Here is the code I am using to reach the file

```
def reportSystemPath = (pathPrefix + "/${report.cluster.name}" + report.path).replaceAll("//", "/")
Path path = Paths.get(reportSystemPath)

def bytes = byte[]
path.toFile().withInputStream() {
    bytes = it.getBytes()
}
```

Comment: Have you deployed the same war to linux which worked on mac ?
Paste some relevant code

Comment: @sudhir Yes I am deploying the same war. Added a sample of code on my question

Comment: log the path and check, that it's a) there and b) accessible for the user, your tomcat runs as.  also which of those three vars contains the non-ascii-char?  the gstring?  what feeds those var?  if it's from a config file, are you sure, that the config file itself is utf-8?

Comment: @cfrick I already logged the path.toString() and it results exactly to what I expect it to be, and the path is good and accessible because on the same path but with another file without special chars in the filename it works perfectly. The var with the possibility of non-ascii-chars is report.path wich contains the path of my file. To finish, these are not from a config file, even if it was, the path.toString() prints the Ç correctly so this is not the problem

Comment: naïve approaches like `touch "ï.txt"; LOCALE=fr_FR.UTF-8 groovy -e 'assert java.nio.file.Paths.get("ï.txt").toFile().exists()'` work for me.  so i'd rather not assume a general problem.

Comment: @cfrick I found out what the real problem is. It is the fact that I get the path from a SQL database, and, for example, the character Ç is stored as the unicode "\u00c3\u0087" , and the only understandable unicode to open a file with this special character is "C\u0327(combinated cedilla)"...